# Insert RichTextBox in Excel userform

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform in Excel VBA. There is plain text box called "Text box1" which contains few text formatting codes (ex. `<Font Color=Black></Font>`).

I need to insert a RichTextBox to show the formatted text in "Text box1".

Comment: Are you planning to distribute your excel file to other users? If yes, then adding a RTB to your form is not advisable

Comment: no I am not distrubuting

Comment: @siddharth-rout. No I am not distributing excel to others

Comment: `OPTION 1:` http://elcha-en.blogspot.in/2015/02/richtextbox-in-excel_2.html `OPTION 2:` The Rich Textbox control does not come with MS Office - it is a VB6 control "Richtx32.ocx" . You have to add reference to the ocx via references and then work with it. You can find lot of examples in Google

Answer (score 1):

Under Tools/Additional Controls find:
Microsoft Rich Textbox Control 6.0 SP6

If it is not installed
you can get it [here](http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/RICHTX32.CAB)

For more help you can find your question [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26147999/How-to-add-a-RichTextBox-Control-for-a-VBA-Application-for-Microsoft-Word.html)

Comment: The link to "http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/RICHTX32.CAB" is dead.