# Export formatted bullets to an email from Excel TextBox

Tags: html, excel, outlook, vba

I've been working on a spread sheet to allow my team to manage our workload more effectively, whilst the business is developing a new tool. Anyway, what the sheet does is inject information, then at the click of a button, it populates an OFT email template so that the info can be sent out.

Problem is, we rely heavily on bullet lists for our emails, and I'm really struggling to find a way of adding bullets effectively from an ActiveX Textbox.

At the moment, I have a button which adds the follow to a text box:

[bullets]
* Bullet 1
* Bullet 2
* Bullet 3
[/bullets]

I then have Replace statements that look for strings and it replaces them with the appropriate HTML tags. Here's the code:

```
' Add HTML formatting to text updates so it displays correctly in the email.
LatestUpdate.Text = Replace(LatestUpdate, "[bullets]", "<ul>")
LatestUpdate.Text = Replace(LatestUpdate, "[/bullets]", "</ul>")
LatestUpdate.Text = Replace(LatestUpdate, "* ", "<li>")
LatestUpdate.Text = Replace(LatestUpdate, vbCrLf, "<br>")
```

The problem I'm having, is that non-technical people are using this document, so I would really like to have it in such a way were they don't have to look at the markup, but can simple add bullets straight from the textbox.

I was originally thinking about replacing "* " with "< li >" however, that doesn't add the correct < ul > tags, so it's not actually a bullet list within the email.

Can anyone help in simplifying this process for the end users please? I'm really stuck.

The holy grail would be to enable rich text formatting on the textbox, but I don't believe that's possible from all the research I've done?

TIA.

Comment: Have a look at this. You should be able to add a rich textbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051237/insert-richtextbox-in-userform-excelvba

Comment: Thanks Zac, unfortunately, "additional controls" is disabled in our environment by the looks of things (it's greyed out).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, what you are looking for is not just a bullet point in your textbox but indentation as well. So here is an attempt at it:

First add the below in your `<textbox>_KeyUp` function:

```
Private Sub txtBulletPoints_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim STRING_LENGTH As Long: STRING_LENGTH = 49
    Dim aLine() As String
    Dim aLineSpace() As String
    Dim iC As Integer
    Dim sText As String
    Dim bUpdate As Boolean

    ' Only do this if there is a string to work with
    If Len(Me.txtBulletPoints.Text) > 0 Then

        ' Set initial values
        aLine = Split(Me.txtBulletPoints.Text, vbCrLf)
        bUpdate = False

        ' First lets indent the last line if we need to
        If Left(aLine(UBound(aLine)), 2) = "- " Then
            For iC = LBound(aLine) To UBound(aLine)
                If iC = UBound(aLine) Then
                    sText = sText & vbTab & aLine(iC)
                Else
                    sText = sText & aLine(iC) & vbCrLf
                End If
            Next

            Me.txtBulletPoints.Text = sText

        End If

        ' Now the tricky bit. Check if we have reached the end of the
        ' line so that we can indent the text into the next line
        If (Len(aLine(UBound(aLine))) >= STRING_LENGTH) And (InStr(1, aLine(UBound(aLine)), vbTab) = 1) Then
            For iC = LBound(aLine) To UBound(aLine)
                If iC = UBound(aLine) Then
                    aLineSpace = Split(aLine(iC), " ")

                    ' As we have to indent the last bullet point line, call the finction to do that
                    sText = sText & SetIndentsInString(aLine(iC), STRING_LENGTH)

                Else
                    sText = sText & aLine(iC) & vbCrLf
                End If
            Next

            Me.txtBulletPoints.Text = sText

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Now add the below UDF where your form code is (essentially at the same place where your `<textbox>_KeyUp` function is):

```
Function SetIndentsInString(ByVal sString As String, ByVal iIndentLen As Long) As String
    Dim iC As Long
    Dim iLastTab As Long: iLastTab = 0
    Dim aSpace() As String
    Dim aTab() As String
    Dim sCurString As String

    ' Check if the string is the same as what it was last
    ' time (sLastString is a private module variable initialised
    ' to "" when the form is activated)
    If Replace(sString, vbTab, "") = Replace(sLastString, vbTab, "") Then
        ' Its the same string so lets return it as is
        SetIndentsInString = sString
    Else
        ' Its not the same string so set initial values
        sLastString = sString
        SetIndentsInString = ""

        ' Loop to see how many lines we have based on number of TABs in the string
        Do While InStr(iLastTab + 1, sString, vbTab) > 0
            iLastTab = iLastTab + InStr(iLastTab + 1, sString, vbTab)
        Loop

        ' If there is only 1 TAB, simply indent the line
        If iLastTab = 1 Then
            aSpace = Split(sString, " ")
            SetIndentsInString = Mid(sString, 1, Len(sString) - Len(aSpace(UBound(aSpace)))) & vbTab & "  " & aSpace(UBound(aSpace))
        Else

            ' More then 1 TAB.. damn!. Ok well lets work it
            aTab = Split(sString, vbTab)
            sCurString = aTab(UBound(aTab))

            ' Check if the last line of our bullet point has more characters then allowed in a line
            If Len(sCurString) >= iIndentLen Then

                ' It does. Now loop through all the lines in our bullet point and set the last character in a new line with indent
                aSpace = Split(sCurString, " ")
                For iC = LBound(aTab) To UBound(aTab)
                    If iC = UBound(aTab) Then
                        SetIndentsInString = SetIndentsInString & Mid(sCurString, 1, Len(sCurString) - Len(aSpace(UBound(aSpace)))) & vbTab & "  " & aSpace(UBound(aSpace))
                    Else
                        SetIndentsInString = SetIndentsInString & aTab(iC) & vbTab
                    End If
                Next

            Else

                ' It doesnt. Loop through and send the string back
                SetIndentsInString = sString

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Function
```

Now in the same module, make the following declaration at the top:

```
Private sLastString As String
```

Essentially the above will act **`like`** a bullet point as it would be in a Rich Text box. Things to remember is that you will have to set `STRING_LENGTH` to the number of characters your textbox will take in a given bullet point line (you will have to play around with that). Below is a screen print of how it worked for me
[image]

Comment: Thanks Zac, unfortunately, that didn't work as desired. The output didn't come out as bullets, but rather a single line of text with bullet marks in between. E.g.: "This is an update with bullets: • Bullet 1 • Bullet 2 • Bullet 3"

Comment: It wasn't meant to come out as bullet points. But users can just type "- " to indicate a bullet point and then you should be able to run your `Replace` on it to convert it to a bullet point in the email. This way they won't need to add `"[bullets]"` tag in textbox

Comment: Ah, I see. It still doesn't really achieve the goal though, as this will just give a line that starts with a bullet point. What I need is actual bullets so that longer bullets that go over multiple lines remain indented and people can add nested bullets etc.

Nested bullets can be easily fixed just by replacing "- -" with two "tabs" before the bullet. But long strings of text will not indent so they remain inline. If I can fix that, I'm on a winner.

Comment: Interesting little project to re-invent bullet points with indentation. Might still not be what you need but I enjoyed doing it :)

Comment: Apologies for the delay in reply. I'm not trying to re-invent the bullet, but I do want a HTML formatted bullet list, rather than some text with a bullet point at the start of the line. This will allow users to format the text correctly within the email, and add to the bullet list if they need to. I hope that's clear.

So to get from where I am now, I'd need the code to look for the first line with the appropriate bullet string (e.g. "- ") and replace the first instance of it with < em > < li >, then replace all other instances with just < li >, then the final instance with < /li > < /em >