Possible to format lines of textbox based on criteria?
I am populating a textbox line by line depending on the property of a value.
If conditionA Then
  Test.TextBox1.Value = Test.TextBox1.Value + vbLf + ValueA
Else
  Test.TextBox1.Value = Test.TextBox1.Value + vbLf + ValueA
End If

This will produce a textbox which looks something like
ValueA
ValueA
ValueB
ValueA

I would like to style all lines that contain ValueA bold and all lines that contain ValueB italic and grey.
Is that possible somehow?
Thank you
Alex

You will need to use a rich text box instead of standard textbox
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051237/insert-richtextbox-in-excel-userform

I tried adding RichTextBox but the system does not accept it (not trustworthy). Is there another way?

A rich text box is the only way to apply different styles, fonts, etc. to parts of the same text block.  Or a possible workaround is to create a separate textbox for each value and set the style for each one -- set the background color and line spacing appropriately to make it "look" like it's all in the same textbox.  Kind of a kludgy way to do it.  Or change the way you present the list to the user.

Thank you both. I will see what I can do. Maybe I can somehow allow RichTextBox. If not, I will maybe create one textbox per criteria.
